# Open cover of $\mathbb C$

Tags: general-topology

Today one of my students asked an interesting question, which I was unable to answer. Concretely:

Let $(z_n)_{n\in \mathbb N^+}$ be an enumeration of $\mathbb Q+\mathrm i\mathbb Q$. The question is, whether $(B_{1/n}(z_n))_{n\in \mathbb N^+}$ is a cover of $\mathbb C$, i.e. if
$$
\mathbb C\subseteq \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_{1/n}(z_n).
$$
It is intuitively clear (?) that this should hold. For every $z\in \mathbb C$ there exists a subsequence $(z_{n_k})_{k\in \mathbb N}$ converging to $z$, since $\mathbb Q+\mathrm i\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb C$. I am however unable to show that we can find $k\in \mathbb N$, such that $|z-z_{n_k}|<\frac{1}{n_k}$. It's somewhat awkward, since we have the same index $n_k$ on both sides and I am not sure how to deal with this.

Thanks for any insights!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Note that the sum of the areas covered by the balls (disregarding overlaps) is  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {\pi}{n^2}=\frac {\pi^3}6,$$
which is considerably less than the area of the complex plane.

Comment: Thank you very much! My intuition was apparently fooling me.

Comment: This was exactly the answer I was writing.

Comment: @XanderHenderson  I'm just happy to see a (relatively) natural computation resulting in the appearance of $\pi^3$.

Comment: @NicoZimmer  Yeah, intuition isn't your friend in this sort of thing.

Comment: I like the phrasing here "which is _considerably_ less than the area of the complex plane". Well, about infinitely many times less, give or take :).

Comment: @NicoZimmer  Not sure what level your students are at, but if they haven't seen the computation of the sum of the square reciprocals, it's not needed here.  The sum clearly converges and that's enough.

Comment: @lulu: We're doing multivariable real analysis, so students should be well aware of this series. I feel somewhat ashamed now though, seeing how wrong I really was.

Comment: Here is an interesting extension to the problem:  suppose that the ball centered at $z_n$ has *volume* $1/n$.  The series no longer converges.  What now? :P

Comment: @NicoZimmer  These things are famously unintuitive.  My advice is to set aside intuition entirely when approaching them.

Comment: @XanderHenderson  Right, just take radius $\frac 1{\sqrt n}$ and the simple argument evaporates.   Of course, if you can select the enumeration, the same argument holds.  Just put all the square free indexed rationals inside the unit circle and the rest can't possibly cover the complement of circle.

Comment: @lulu My solution was to put the powers of 2 outside the unit circle, but yes, same idea.

Answer (score 4):

In comments, it is further asked that we cover $\mathbb{Q}+i\mathbb{Q}$ with $B_{\frac1{\sqrt{n}}}(z_n)$.

Enumerate $(z_n\in\mathbb{Q}+i\mathbb{Q}:n\ge1)=\mathbb{Q}+i\mathbb{Q}$ so that $|z_n-e|\gt\frac1{\sqrt{n}}$. Then
$$
e\not\in\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B_{\frac1{\sqrt{n}}}(c_n)\tag1
$$

---

**Details of the Enumeration**

Define a sequence of enumerations of annuli for $k\ge1$:
$$
W_k=\left(w_{k,j}\in\mathbb{Q}+i\mathbb{Q}:j\ge1\text{ and }\sqrt{\frac2{k^2+k}}\lt|w_{k,j}-e|\le\sqrt{\frac2{k^2-k}}\right)\tag2
$$
where
$$
\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty W_k=\mathbb{Q}+i\mathbb{Q}\tag3
$$
Put these enumerations into a single enumeration by diagonalization:
$$
z_n=w_{k,j}\tag4
$$
where
$$
\begin{align}
m&=\left\lfloor\frac{1+\sqrt{8n-7}}2\right\rfloor\tag{5a}\\
k&=n-\frac{m^2-m}2\tag{5b}\\[9pt]
j&=m-k+1\tag{5c}
\end{align}
$$
Here are tables of some results from $(5)$:
$$
\begin{array}{}
\begin{array}[t]{c|c|c|c}
  n & m & k & j \\
  \hline
  1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
  2 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\
  3 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
  4 & 3 & 1 & 3 \\
  5 & 3 & 2 & 2 \\
  6 & 3 & 3 & 1 \\
  7 & 4 & 1 & 4 \\
  8 & 4 & 2 & 3 \\
  9 & 4 & 3 & 2 \\
  10 & 4 & 4 & 1
\end{array}&
\begin{array}[t]{c|c|c|c}
  n & m & k & j \\
  \hline
  11 & 5 & 1 & 5 \\
  12 & 5 & 2 & 4 \\
  13 & 5 & 3 & 3 \\
  14 & 5 & 4 & 2 \\
  15 & 5 & 5 & 1 \\
  16 & 6 & 1 & 6 \\
  17 & 6 & 2 & 5 \\
  18 & 6 & 3 & 4 \\
  19 & 6 & 4 & 3 \\
  20 & 6 & 5 & 2 \\
  21 & 6 & 6 & 1
\end{array}
\end{array}\tag6
$$

Note that $n=\frac{k^2+k}2+j-1$. This means that the first time
that an element of $W_k$ is seen is when $n=\frac{k^2+k}2$. Thus,
$$
n\lt\frac{k^2+k}2\implies z_n\in\bigcup\limits_{j=1}^{k-1}W_j\tag7
$$
For any $n\ge1$, there is a $k\ge2$ so that $\frac{k^2-k}2\le n\lt\frac{k^2+k}2$. Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
|z_n-e|
&\gt\sqrt{\frac2{k^2-k}}\tag{8a}\\
&\ge\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\tag{8b}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(8a):}$ apply $(2)$ and $(7)$
$\text{(8b):}$ $n\ge\frac{k^2-k}2$

Comment: So basically, whenever $r_n\to 0 (n\to\infty)$ you can choose the enumeration $z_n$ of $\mathbb Q+i\mathbb Q$ such that $e$ is not covered? I guess this is pretty much what you are claiming here. Would be really nice to expand that to a full proof.

Comment: I think that any monotonically increasing function from $[0,\infty)$ onto itself can replace the square root in $(2)$ and $(8)$.